# How to force the optimizer to keep some code in Julia?

Tags: julia, benchmarking, microbenchmark

How to force evaluation of an expression so it wouldn't get optimized out?

`@elapsed f()` returns zero, as the result of pure function `f` is unused.

In Rust we can use an intrinsic called `black_box`, in Nim - `used` pragma, in C we can make a `volatile` variable, in Zig - `doNotOptimizeAway` function, in Haskell we can use `evaluate` to force the evaluation, and so on. How can i do this in Julia?

---

Also, is `@elapsed` actually the proper way to measure elapsed time? I personally need a monotonic timer with nanosecond precision...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have not seen it already, [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) may be what you're looking for.

`Base.donotdelete` will prevent dead code elimination (but won't stop `f()` from being optimized into a constant, if that's possible).

```
f() = maximum(i^2 for i = 1:1000000000)

timeit1() = @elapsed f()
timeit2() = @elapsed Base.donotdelete(f())

timeit1() # 0.0
timeit2() # 0.36 ish
```

`@elapsed` uses `Base.time_ns()`, so it has nanosecond precision.

Comment: Thanks, both `donotdelete` and `time_ns` worked perfectly